# How do you get neighboring pixels of a bitmap Allocation in Renderscript?

Tags: android, image-processing, renderscript

I want to perform an image processing operation that needs neighboring pixels, but I'm not sure how to access them from an allocation. Most kernels I have seen operate on a single pixel, update it, and then return it. Is there a way I can access the neighbors of (x, y) in the method below.

```
uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) invert(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {

  uchar4 neighbor = allocation[x+1][y]; // How do I do this in renderscript?
  uchar4 otherNeighbor = allocation[x-1][y]; 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard input/output allocations that get implicitly connected are harder to access for neighboring pixels, but you can get to them by just creating a global variable of type rs_allocation.

```
rs_allocation input;
uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) invert(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {

uchar4 neighbor = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(input, x+1, y);
uchar4 otherNeighbor = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(input, x-1, y);
...
}
```

In Java, before you call forEach on your kernel, you just need to do:

```
myScript.set_input(myInputAllocation);
myScript.forEach_invert(myInputAllocation, myOutputAllocation);
```

Comment: One thing I didn't do in my naive code was bounds check my accesses. If you run that code directly, you will attempt to access invalid memory (for any valid input Allocation). You should clamp the (x-1) and (x+1) parts based on the dimensions of your kernel.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I've setup two global variables, maxWidth & maxHeight, and will check against those.

Comment: You can also call rsAllocationGetDimX(input) and/or rsAllocationGetDimY(input) as needed inside your .rs file too.

Comment: @StephenHines Suppose I want to do the same, but for output, what should I do ? I've asked about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33056776/878126

Answer (score 0):

You can, do this:

```
...
uchar4 neighbor = rsGetElementAt(in, x + 1, y);
uchar4 otherNeighbor = rsGetElementAt(in, x - 1, y);
...
```

Comment: You can't because in is not an rs_allocation. The standard input/output allocations that get implicitly connected are harder to access for neighboring pixels, but you can get to them by just creating a global variable of type rs_allocation. I will provide a more complete answer below.

Comment: Damn...I was afraid of that.  Thanks for clarifying, Stephen.