# Can I set input and output allocations on Renderscript to be of different sizes/dimensions?

Tags: android, rotation, renderscript

### Background

I'm trying to learn Renderscript, so I wish to try to do some simple operations that I think about.

### The problem

I thought of rotating a bitmap, which is something that's simple enough to manage.

on C/C++, it's a simple thing to do (search for "jniRotateBitmapCw90") :

https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations/blob/master/JniBitmapOperationsLibrary/jni/JniBitmapOperationsLibrary.cpp

Thing is, when I try this on Renderscript, I get this error:

> android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Dimension mismatch
>   between parameters ain and aout!

Here's what I do:

RS:

```
void rotate90CW(const uchar4 *in, uchar4 *out, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    // XY. ..X ... ... 
    // ...>..Y>...>Y..
    // ... ... .YX X.. 
    out[...]=in[...] ...
}
```

Java:

```
    mRenderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
    mInBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sample_photo);
    mOutBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mInBitmap.getHeight(), mInBitmap.getWidth(), mInBitmap.getConfig());
    final Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRenderScript, mInBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    final Allocation output = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRenderScript, mOutBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    ScriptC_test script = new ScriptC_test(mRenderScript, getResources(), R.raw.test);
    ...
    script.forEach_rotate90CW(input, output);
    output.copyTo(mOutBitmap);
```

Even when I do set both allocations to be of the same size (squared bitmap), and I just set the output to be the input:

```
out[width * y + x] = in[width * y+x];
```

- then what I get is a bitmap with holes... How come?

This is what I get:

[image]

### The questions

1. Does this mean I can't do this kind of operation?
2. Does it mean that I can't use allocations of various sizes/dimensions?
3. Is it possible to overcome this issue (and still use Renderscript, of course) ? If so, how?
   Maybe I could add an array variable inside the RS side, and set the allocation to it, instead?
4. Why do I get holes in the bitmap, for the case of a square input&output?

---

EDIT:This is my current code:

RS

```
rs_allocation *in;
```

uchar4 **attribute**((kernel)) rotate90CW(uint32_t x, uint32_t y){
        // XY. ..X ... ...
        // ...>..Y>...>Y..
        // ... ... .YX X..
        uchar4 curIn =rsGetElementAt_uchar4(in, 0, 0);
        return curIn; //just for testing...
    }

Java:

```
    mRenderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
    mInBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sample_photo);
    mOutBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mInBitmap.getHeight(), mInBitmap.getWidth(), mInBitmap.getConfig());
    final Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRenderScript, mInBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    final Allocation output = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRenderScript, mOutBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    ScriptC_test script = new ScriptC_test(mRenderScript, getResources(), R.raw.test);

    script.bind_in(input);
    script.forEach_rotate90CW(output);
    output.copyTo(mOutBitmap);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mOutBitmap);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here goes:

> 1. Does this mean I can't do this kind of operation?

No, not really.  You just have to craft things correctly.

> 2. Does it mean that I can't use allocations of various sizes/dimensions?

No, but it does mean you can't use different size allocations in the way you currently are doing things.  The default kernel in/out mechanism expects the input and output sizes to match so it can iterate over all of the elements correctly.  If you need something different, it's up to you to manage it.  More on that below.

> 3. Is it possible to overcome this issues...how?

The easiest solution would be to create an Allocation for input and bind it to the renderscript instance rather than pass it as a parameter.  Then your RS would only need an output allocation (and your kernel only take output, x and y).  From there you can determine which coordinate within the input allocation you want and place it directly into the output location:

```
int inX = ...;
int inY = ...;
uchar4 curIn = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inAlloc, inX, inY);
*out = curIn;
```

> 4. Why do I get holes in the bitmap, for the case of a square input&output?

It's because you cannot use the x and y parameters to offset into the input and output allocation.  Those in/out parameters are already pointing to the correct (same) location in both the input and output.  The indexing you're doing is unnecessary and not really supported.  Each time your kernel is called, it is being called for 1 element location within the allocation.  This is why the input and output sizes must be the same when provided as parameters.

Comment: 1. Nice. 2. So it iterates over each allocation element, one after another, so that each "in" matches each "out"? 3. How should the "inAlloc" be declared and used (in both RS and Java) ? 4. I didn't expect to see a nearly-correct representation of the bitmap this way, then. Odd. The correct one should have been *out=*in; , then?

Comment: 1. :-)  2. Yes.  Note that it is also doing this in parallel, so you cannot assume any serialized order. 3. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/advanced.html) under the section "Working with Memory" section. 4. It's kinda funky, but most likely due to synchronization. The references to allocation locations (in/out) which are passed in are not intended to be indexed like this, so it's not out of the question.  If you're trying to do a 90 degree shift, you don't out *out = *in since that would just be a copy.

Comment: 1+2+3. OK, thank you. I've read it but I still don't see how to do it. They don't about struct, but not an array/bitmap data. Do you also know of a webpage that shows a list of all available functions of RS that I can use (like "rsGetElementAt..." that you used) ? 4. The last example was of trying to set the output the same as the input, which is why I wrote "...and I just set the output to be the input" . I wanted to see if I can at least set the output to be like the input.

Comment: Maybe you mean the part of "int32_t *intPointer" ?

Comment: The rsGetElementAt_uchar4 doesn't seem to exist: "error: no matching function for call to 'rsGetElementAt_uchar4' " . How come?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_allocation_data.html#android_rs:rsGetElementAt has docs about this. You can also see more functions at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/overview.html for the runtime part of RS. What API level are you targeting (re: missing support for the uchar4 variant)? Are you using the support library?

Comment: I've tried updating the versions, but now I get even more errors. Now it says it's being used: "Error:Timeout waiting to lock buildscript class cache for build file '...build.gradle' (...caches\2.4\scripts\...\ProjectScript\buildscript). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance." . The version I had before is "renderscriptTargetApi 18" , compileSdkVersion 23, buildToolsVersion '22.0.1' . The reason was that newer versions caused issues: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188096 . The RS tools really are very buggy and hard to use.

Comment: OK, I've killed all processes of Android-Studio, and updated renderscriptTargetApi  to 22 , but now I get this error at runtime (when I don't use the special function "rsGetElementAt_uchar4" ) : android.support.v8.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: API 20+ only allows simple 1D allocations to be used with bind. " .

Comment: Yes. Bind is deprecated so you should be using rs_allocation with an appropriate Type.

Comment: I just don't get how come the tools have so many issues even now. I've reported about them multiple times (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182302 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182356 ) , but still they can't work well.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

RS

```c
rs_allocation *in;  
uchar4 attribute((kernel)) rotate90CW(uint32_t x, uint32_t y){
...
uchar4 curIn =rsGetElementAt_uchar4(in, x, y); 

return curIn; 
 }
```

Comment: Sadly I have no idea how to use Renderscript anymore, especially on Android Studio.